# Automated tests using embedded RavenDB fail on TeamCity but not when run via R# or NUnit

Tags: teamcity, ravendb

I'm developing an application using RavenDB. I have automated tests that work against an embedded in-memory database. All tests were working fine when I was referencing Raven build 2033-Unstable. I upgraded to build 2067-Unstable (and now 2069) and am now getting an exception in every NUnit test when run via TeamCity (7.1 build 23907). All tests run fine when run via R# or NUnit GUI.

The exception I'm receiving appears to be a `NullReferenceException` inside Raven at `Raven.Bundles.Versioning.Triggers.VersioningPutTrigger.AllowPut(String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Bundles\Versioning\Triggers\VersioningPutTrigger.cs:line 22`. I'm not even using the `Versioning` bundle.

Here's the full stack trace :

```
Test(s) failed. Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details.
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at AppCenter.Tests.Fixture.Resolve[TService]() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Tests\Fixture.cs:line 40
   at AppCenter.Tests.Fixture.get_Raven() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Tests\Fixture.cs:line 22
   at AppCenter.Tests.Fixture.Store[T](T entity) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Tests\Fixture.cs:line 50
   at AppCenter.Tests.AppAdmin.ApplicationEditTests.TestLoad() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Tests\AppAdmin\ApplicationEditTests.cs:line 20
--NullReferenceException
   at Raven.Bundles.Versioning.Triggers.VersioningPutTrigger.AllowPut(String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Bundles\Versioning\Triggers\VersioningPutTrigger.cs:line 22
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass42.<AssertPutOperationNotVetoed>b__3f(AbstractPutTrigger trigger) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 601
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.AssertPutOperationNotVetoed(String key, RavenJObject metadata, RavenJObject document, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 600
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass3a.<Put>b__33(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 551
   at Raven.Storage.Managed.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Storage\Managed\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 131
   at Raven.Storage.Managed.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Storage\Managed\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 112
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Put(String key, Nullable`1 etag, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 543
   at Raven.Bundles.Encryption.Settings.EncryptionSettingsManager.VerifyEncryptionKey(DocumentDatabase database, EncryptionSettings settings) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Bundles\Encryption\Settings\EncryptionSettingsManager.cs:line 114
   at Raven.Database.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Apply[T](IEnumerable`1 self, Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Extensions\EnumerableExtensions.cs:line 18
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.InitializeTriggersExceptIndexCodecs() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 221
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 200
   at Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Embedded\EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs:line 208
   at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentStore.cs:line 431
   at AppCenter.Config.RavenModule.Initialize(DocumentStoreBase store) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Framework\Config\RavenModule.cs:line 32
   at AppCenter.Tests.RavenInMemoryModule.<Load>b__1(IActivatingEventArgs`1 a) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Tests\RavenInMemoryModule.cs:line 25
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClass6.<OnActivating>b__5(Object s, ActivatingEventArgs`1 e)
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.RaiseActivating(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at AppCenter.Config.RavenModule.<Load>b__1(IComponentContext c) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\994e66c6c107022f\AppCenter.Framework\Config\RavenModule.cs:line 19
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

I'm using Autofac to wire it up, and that code looks like this:

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new EmbeddableDocumentStore
                              {
                                  RunInMemory = true,
                                  Configuration =
                                      {
                                          PluginsDirectory = GetPluginsDirectory()
                                      }
                              })
            .OnActivating(a => RavenModule.Initialize(a.Instance))
            .As<IDocumentStore>()
            .Named<IDocumentStore>("test")
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

    private static string GetPluginsDirectory()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof (UniqueConstraintsPutTrigger).Assembly.Location);
    }

    public static void Initialize(DocumentStoreBase store)
    {
        store.RegisterListener(new UniqueConstraintsStoreListener());
        store.Initialize();
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof (RavenModule).Assembly, store);
        RequireTrigger(store, typeof (UniqueConstraintsPutTrigger));
    }

    private static void RequireTrigger(IDocumentStore store, Type triggerType)
    {
        var installedTriggerNames = store.DatabaseCommands.GetStatistics().Triggers.Select(t => t.Name);

        if (!installedTriggerNames.Contains(triggerType.ToString()))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(
                "The required trigger '{0}' was not detected. Verify the bundle '{1}' been installed into the" +
                " server's plugins directory.",
                triggerType, Path.GetFileName(triggerType.Assembly.Location)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: First things I'd be checking are verifying the assemblies for Raven on the build server are the same as you expect them to be.

Comment: I've done that; even ran the compiled assemblies from the build server directly on my machine without error. That's the real frustrating part.

Comment: Next steps are reducing the complexity until you can get what is really happening, I'd start with removing autofac and instead wire things up with a couple of helper classes as needed, or use no parameter constructors to use poor man's dependency injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Setting the `PluginsDirectory` to be the same folder as all the other DLLs, particularly `Raven.Database.dll`, was causing all the plugins embedded in that DLL be be unintentionally loaded as well. Not all of the Raven plugins work together, so loading them all caused exceptions. By making a separate `Plugins` directory, and copying `Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints.dll` into that made the exception stop happening.

I still don't understand why it only failed from the build server; it seems like it should have failed locally as well.